# How can i save state my button(change class name) after refresh?

Tags: jquery

I want to save state of button after click(change the class name), I have two codes found after hours of searching, but none of them works properly, default class is set after refresh,  can someone tell what's wrong with them ?

```
<script>
    var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('classChange');
    if (retrievedObject) {
        $('#tick').addClass(retrievedObject)
    }  
    $("#tick").click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("btn btn-light")) {
            $(this).removeClass('btn btn-light').addClass('.btn btn-success');
            localStorage.setItem('class', '.btn btn-success');
            return false;
        } else {
            $('.btn btn-success').removeClass('.btn btn-success').addClass('btn btn-light');
            localStorage.setItem('classChange', 'btn btn-light');    
            return false;
        }
    });
</script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if (localStorage.getItem('classChange'))
            $(this).toggleClass('.btn btn-success');

        $('#tick').on('click', function () {          
            $(this).toggleClass('.btn btn-success');
            localStorage.setItem('classChange', true);           
            return false;
        });


    });
</script>
```

Comment: $(this).toggleClass('.btn btn-success'); should be $(this).toggleClass('btn btn-success'); (remove the .)

Comment: Several discrepancies in your code. Sometime you are setting item as 'class' and sometimes as 'classChange'. The value sometimes include a period and other times not. Basically do not store the period in the local storage value, make sure names are consistence, and stick to one (first) code.  And no need to store 'btn' with your class.

Comment: thanks, but it still doesn't work, same default class after refresh

Comment: I am not using both of them, just trying them but none of the worked, I corrected mistakes as you wrote but still the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically do not store the period in the local storage value, make sure names are consistence, and no need to store 'btn' with your class

```
<script>
    var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('classChange');
    if (retrievedObject) {
        $('#tick').addClass(retrievedObject)
    }  
    $("#tick").click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("btn-light")) {
            $(this).removeClass('btn-light').addClass('btn-success');
            localStorage.setItem('classChange', 'btn-success');                
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-light');
            localStorage.setItem('classChange', 'btn-light');                
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks very much , I will try this corrected code now

Comment: I have updated and cleaned up the code further. How many buttons do you have? from your code you should have only one button with ID = "tick".

Comment: Also verify that the value is stored in localstorage by simply doing console.log(localStorage.getItem('classChange'));